# Failed to verify PGP signature from ISO Archlinux

Tags: pgp

I've downloaded the last release from Archlinux and I verify successfully the checksum SHA1 and MD5 but when I'm trying to verify the PGP signature using 
`Kleopatra` from `GPG4win` I'm getting the following error :

> Signed on 2017-02-01 17:28 with unknown certificate 0x7F2D434B9741E8AC.
>   The signature is invalid: No public certificate to verify the signature

The PGP signature is from https://www.archlinux.org/download/.

My question is does the signature was corrupted or do I missed something in the process to verify it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: To verify a signature you need to have the  public part of the key which was used for signing. Looks like you don't have it. Check out https://www.archlinux.org/people/developers/ for the keys which are used in signing.

Comment: Gatcha! Thanks very much for your reply Steffen! 

I found the public part from the dev at Archlinux : https://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?op=vindex&fingerprint=on&exact=on&search=0x7F2D434B9741E8AC

Feel free to post your comment as an answer it was definitely what I was looking for.